# How is this Android interaction done?

Tags: android, user-interface, notifications, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm working on developing an app that runs in the background. We want to notify users who are in a different app that something in the original app happened, and they need to take action. We could use the notification system, but this doesn't provide the level of attention we desire.

We found a perfect example of what we'd like to do in an app called Any.do - a reminder/list app. When you set a reminder, it appears in some sort of slider window/drawer that comes up from the bottom of your screen.

You can see a screen shot of this at my dropbox at the link below:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48702/anydo.png

Can someone inform me of how this is done? I don't see anything in the permissions for the app that might suggest what this is.

Thanks!

Comment: You can call an activity with `Theme.Dialog` from your service to show a Dialog on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the BroadcastReceiver class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). This will allow you to schedule events after a specified amount of time. It is very easy to use and very simple to set up. There are tons of tutorials on using it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! So is what is actually showing in that shot an example of an intent then?

Comment: Do you want an example?

Comment: Sure - that would be great. :)

Comment: This is a great reference http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html